# How to iterate over the remaining items in a dict while looping through that dict?

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

Is there a cleaner way to iterate over the follow-up keys of a dict when iterating over a dict?

```py
d = { "a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3 }

k = list(d.keys())

for i in range(len(k)):
    print(k[i] + ":")
    for j in range(i+1, len(k)):
        print("\t" + k[j])
```

```
a:
    b
    c
b:
    c
c:
```

It feels like it should be possible to use iterators.

Comment: OrderedDict will handle this case, it treats the keys as a fixed order: https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict

Comment: @grey_ranger dicts are ordered since Python 3.7 anyway.

Comment: @grey_ranger ordering isn't important in my use-case; I only need to iterate over the remaining keys. Does OrderedDict have something for that?

Comment: What about `for i,j in itertools.combinations(d,2)):` ? Not a pure drop-in replacement, because it doesn't lend itself easily to printing `k[i]+":"` once for each key - it depends what your real use case is.

Comment: @slothrop I think I can make use of `itertools.combinations` for my problem

Comment: Cool. You also could wrap it in `itertools.groupby` if you wanted a way to do the equivalent of `print(k[i]+":")`, i.e. have a step that runs exactly once for each "first" key.

Comment: @Fravadona What exactly does "cleaner" mean in this context? Your question doesn't really explain what is wrong with your current solution. At present, `dict` doesn't support indexing, so your solution is about efficient as it could be, since it only creates a single copy of the keys.

Comment: @ekhumoro Well, I didn't like my solution when I came up with it. Wouldn't you say that the proposed answers are a little "cleaner"?

Comment: @Fravadona Most of the answers add several unnecessary complications which make the code less efficient without improving readability. The solution that uses iterators might be more effiicient with a very large `dict`, but is otherwise no more readable than the original solution. Is it really worth importing an extra module for such a trivial piece of code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two iterator solutions...

This one explicitly creates an iterator so we can access it (unlike the implicit iterator used by `for k in d:`). Then we iterate over that iterator. After getting each key via the `for k in keys:`, the iterator is an iterator over the remaining keys. A shallow copy lets us iterate over them without disturbing our main iterator and without copying the dict contents.

```py
from copy import copy

d = { "a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3 }

keys = iter(d)
for k in keys:
    print(k + ":")
    for k in copy(keys):
        print("\t" + k)
```

Output ([Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY3Z6QV5ecqJOcXVCpk5hbkF5WA2VxcKQq2CtUKSolKVgqGOgpKSUDaCEgnA2ljhVouruzUymKgksyS1CKNFE2utPwihWyFzDwFkLgVlwIQFBRl5pVoZCtoKyhZKWmCheCqQHZogJRqQtQi1CvFlCgBtWRrQtwHdSbMuQA)):

```
a:
    b
    c
b:
    c
c:
```

Alternatively, with `islice` ([Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=RY49DoJAEIX7PcXLVBCxQBtD4hU8gQ3CEifIDlmGwhhPYkMjd_I2Lj_Gab5k8r6Z9xrbu17FDcO712p7-IyVlwas1qvIrQM3rXgFdzcurDEljniAcsqQJqBL4C6wCNzjaUwlHpygBjtY1zfW52qjMkEaZwZhWs9OoxobUEbxvJqcWVieTOlw4iTOrs7fo7NSUOt4abuW_pX_Ag)):

```py
from itertools import islice

d = { "a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3 }

for i, k in enumerate(d, 1):
    print(k + ":")
    for k in islice(d, i, None):
        print("\t" + k)
```

Each `islice` "skips" the first `i` keys by quickly iterating over them, so that's somewhat wasteful double iteration overall. But it's pretty quick, especially compared to `print`s.

---

Two more solutions, they do copy contents but are shorter than yours.

```
d = { "a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3 }

ks = list(d)
for i, k in enumerate(ks, 1):
    print(k + ":")
    for k in ks[i:]:
        print("\t" + k)
```

```
d = { "a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3 }

ks = list(d)
while ks:
    print(ks.pop(0) + ":")
    for k in ks:
        print("\t" + k)
```

The latter was inspired by [Guy's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77758739/12671057).

Comment: That's what I was looking for, I think^^

Answer (score 2):

```
d = { "a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3 }
k = list(d)
for i in range(len(k)):
    print(k[i], k[i+1:])
```

Comment: That's better indeed; still using a separate list though +1

Comment: @Fravadona I don't see a problem with using an extra list here myself, but if you hated it you could obtain the list each iteration. Perhaps like: `for i, v in enumerate(d): print(v, list(d)[i+1:])`

Comment: My only critique is that it does not technically produce the required output.

Comment: @JonSG It does, with `print(k[i], *k[i+1:], sep="\n\t")`

Comment: @Fravadona Or `print(*k[i:], sep="\n\t")` (and with that, I'd finally find the iterating over `range` acceptable).

Answer (score 1):

Since order is not important you can just pop a key every time and get the rest

```
d = {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}
temp_d = d.copy()
while temp_d:
    print(temp_d.popitem()[0] + ":", temp_d.keys())
```

you can get rid of `temp_d` if you don't need the original dictionary anymore.

Comment: Interesting, I'll try to use it

Comment: This will produce the wrong output. It's not just a matter of order: the grouping still needs to be preserved. Thus `[c, [a, b]], [b, [a]], [a, []]` is clearly not equivalent to `[a, [b, c]], [b, [c]], [c, []]`.

Comment: @ekhumoro *ordering isn't important in my use-case; I only need to iterate over the remaining keys* as I understand it the grouping doesn't meter since the order doesn't. The o.p. didn't say one way or the other.

Answer (score 1):

For an iterator based approach, you could use the `tee` function from itertools to "snapshot" an iterator on the dictionary's keys.

```
from itertools import tee

d = { "a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3 }

iterd = iter(d)
for k in d:
    print(k+":")
    next(iterd)
    iterd,rest = tee(iterd)    
    for k in rest:
        print("\t",k)
```

output:

```
a:
     b
     c
b:
     c
c:
```

*note: This solution, while conceptually interesting, is probably quite bad from an efficiency perspective*

A more efficient solution would be to use a queue:

```
from collections import deque

d = { "a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3 }

qd = deque(d)
while qd:
    print(qd.popleft()+":")  
    for k in qd:
        print("\t",k)
```

or a simple list (without deleting/popping items):

```
d = { "a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3 }

ld = list(d)
for i,k in enumerate(ld,1):
    print(k+":")  
    for j in range(i,len(d)):
        print("\t",ld[j])
```